# Installation of Android licenses on a Mac M1 failure

Tags: android, macos, flutter, dart

I have a problem when I type `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, it constantly displays this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
```

How to remedy this and successfully install the licenses ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also faced the problem to fix this you have to open Android Studio

Then SDK Manager

[image: Android Studio Picture]

Then SDK Tools

[image: SDK Manager]

Then check the Android SDK Command-line Tools and the click apply

[image: Install Command Line tools]

It should Fix your problem

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, it allowed me to solve this problem

Comment: It works for me fine. Thank you very much. (apple macbook air with m1 chip)